# XML, XSLT Group Same Elements by Title With Child Nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to build out an appendix/index page from the outline XML output of `wkhtmltopdf`.

Is there a way to loop through elements and group them by specific attribute value without using the key() function or XSLT 2.0 for-each-group? This is because of some limitation in the XSL processor being use in wkhtmltopdf.

I'm thinking of using the preceding-sibling to check if the title is still the same.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//o:item">
   <xsl:sort select="@title"></xsl:sort>
   <xsl:variable name="key" select="@title" />
   <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::o:item[@title=$key])">
       <xsl:value-of select="$key"></xsl:value-of>
       <xsl:for-each select="current()/o:item">
         <xsl:element name="{@title}" />
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

I'm fairly new with XSLT so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the outline xml from wkhtmltopdf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="toc.xsl"?>
<outline xmlns="http://wkhtmltopdf.org/outline">
    <item title="PDF" page="0" link="__WKANCHOR_0" backLink="__WKANCHOR_1">
        <item title="Type1" page="1" link="__WKANCHOR_2" backLink="__WKANCHOR_3">
            <item title="SubType1" page="1" link="__WKANCHOR_4" backLink="__WKANCHOR_5">
                <item title="Collection1" page="1" link="__WKANCHOR_6" backLink="__WKANCHOR_7">
                    <item title="Item1" page="1" link="__WKANCHOR_8" backLink="__WKANCHOR_9"/>
                </item>
                <item title="Collection2" page="1" link="__WKANCHOR_a" backLink="__WKANCHOR_b">
                    <item title="Item2" page="1" link="__WKANCHOR_c" backLink="__WKANCHOR_d"/>
                    <item title="Item3" page="2" link="__WKANCHOR_e" backLink="__WKANCHOR_f"/>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item title="SubType2" page="3" link="__WKANCHOR_g" backLink="__WKANCHOR_h">
                <item title="Collection1" page="3" link="__WKANCHOR_i" backLink="__WKANCHOR_j">
                    <item title="Item4" page="3" link="__WKANCHOR_k" backLink="__WKANCHOR_l"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
        <item title="Type2" page="4" link="__WKANCHOR_m" backLink="__WKANCHOR_n">
            <item title="SubType1" page="4" link="__WKANCHOR_o" backLink="__WKANCHOR_p">
                <item title="Collection1" page="5" link="__WKANCHOR_u" backLink="__WKANCHOR_v">
                    <item title="Item5" page="4" link="__WKANCHOR_q" backLink="__WKANCHOR_r"/>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item title="SubType3" page="5" link="__WKANCHOR_s" backLink="__WKANCHOR_t">
                <item title="Collection3" page="5" link="__WKANCHOR_u" backLink="__WKANCHOR_v">
                    <item title="Item6" page="5" link="__WKANCHOR_w" backLink="__WKANCHOR_x"/>
                    <item title="Item7" page="5" link="__WKANCHOR_y" backLink="__WKANCHOR_z"/>
                    <item title="Item8" page="5" link="__WKANCHOR_10" backLink="__WKANCHOR_11"/>
                </item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</outline>
```

Expected output is (group all distinct 4th item child items):

```
<Collection1>
    <Item1></Item1>
    <Item4></Item4>
    <Item5></Item5>
</Collection1>
<Collection2>
    <Item2></Item2>
    <Item3></Item3>
</Collection2>
<Collection3>
    <Item6></Item6>
    <Item7></Item7>
    <Item8></Item8>
</Collection3>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<xsl:for-each-group>` and `group-by` on `@title[contains(., 'Collection')]` to prepare the groups and then loop on the `current-group()` to get the elements.

Please try the following **XSLT 2.0** solution

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:o="http://wkhtmltopdf.org/outline">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="//o:item" group-by="@title[contains(., 'Collection')]">
            <xsl:element name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()/o:item">
                    <xsl:element name="{@title}" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In case **XSLT 1.0** is being used then `<xsl:key>` has to be defined and then the loop should run on grouped elements. Below is the XSLT 1.0 solution.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:o="http://wkhtmltopdf.org/outline">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="kTitle" match="//o:item" use="@title[contains(.,'Collection')]" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//o:item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kTitle', @title[contains(.,'Collection')])[1])]">
            <xsl:element name="{@title}">
                <xsl:for-each select="key('kTitle', @title[contains(.,'Collection')])/o:item">
                    <xsl:element name="{@title}" />
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<Collection1>
   <Item1/>
   <Item4/>
   <Item5/>
</Collection1>
<Collection2>
   <Item2/>
   <Item3/>
</Collection2>
<Collection3>
   <Item6/>
   <Item7/>
   <Item8/>
</Collection3>
```

Comment: Thanks @aniket-v! This is exactly what I needed. I didn't think of looping through the current-group.

Comment: I encountered some problems in processing this xsl with the xsl processor included in the wkhtmltopdf. Apparently, it does not support the xsl:for-each-group. I converted the logic here to xsl 1.0 using fn:key() but wkhtmltopdf also doesn't support it. Any other way of accomplishing the same task without the use of xsl:for-each-group and key()?

Comment: @Tim - I have updated the answer with XSLT 1.0 solution. Since the question referenced `for-each-group`, I assumed, you are using XSLT 2.0. The answer now contains both the XSLT approaches.

Comment: @AniketV I was already able to do that for XSLT 1.0 however the XSL processor of wkhtmltopdf (which I think is QTXmlPatterns) don't support the key() function. Any other way to do this? I'm trying to use preceding-sibling but to no avail.

Comment: Here what I got so far:
`<xsl:for-each select="//o:item">
        <xsl:sort select="@title"></xsl:sort>
        <xsl:variable name="key" select="@title" />

        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::o:item[@title=$key])">
            <xsl:value-of select="$key"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:for-each select="current()/o:item">
                <xsl:element name="{@title}" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>`

Comment: Could you please edit the question and add the XSLT code in the question? It is not a good practice to add code in the comments as it becomes difficult to understand.

Comment: @Tim ... Indeed [QtXMLPatterns docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/xmlprocessing.html#xslt-2-0) does have XSLT limitations. Consider using a fully supported, W3C conformant XSLT processor and pass the result into `wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: @Parfait that would be probably my last resort since that would involve a whole lot of more issues to deal with.

Comment: Really? Practically every programming language (Java, C#, Perl, Python, PHP, VB) has fully supported XSLT libraries. Just pick a stack! Plus, Windows PowerShell and Linux/Mac's Bash maintain XSLT processors. Just pick a command line shell! Then there's external ones [Saxon, Xalan, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info). Just pick an .exe!